# How do I change "one time" text in WooCommerce Subscriptions?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I found this very helpful piece of code that allows me to change the text for subscription options, for the life of me I can't find a way to change the one time text to include the price.

```
function change_subscription_product_string( $subscription_string, $product, $include )
{
    if( $include['sign_up_fee'] ){
        $subscription_string = str_replace('sign-up fee', 'something else', $subscription_string);
    }
    return $subscription_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'change_subscription_product_string', 10, 3 );
```

If someone can help me out, I would be incredibly grateful

Comment: Where the "one time" is showing in the website.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.